# How to open SMAP's Surface Moisture data files

Tags: gdal, hdf, radar, nasa, hdf5

I downloaded `surface moisture` data from `Nasa`'s `Soil Moisture Active Passive (SMAP)` sensor website (https://nsidc.org/data/smap/smap-data.html).

For each processing level (1-4), three types of files are present inside each folder: a `*.qa` file, an `*.xml` file, and a `*.h5`file.

I tried to open the `h5` file with `ENVI` but the format could not be recognized on the `Dataset Browser`.

`Gdal` also could not read it as:

```py
dataset = gdal.Open('SMAP_L1C_S0_HIRES_02045_D_20150620T094355_R11850_001.h5')
print dataset.RasterCount
```

returned 0 which means that the bands could not be read.

Comment: It took me less time to Google (hdf5, envi) and find an answer than it took you to write this post. The search pulled up the ENVI help file for OpenHierarchicalData at http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/OpenHierarchicalData.html

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I tried that before posting, and on the `Dataset Browser` I got `This dataset is not supported by ENVI` for every raster. Besides, my question was not on how to open an `hdf` file with `ENVI`, but how to open `SMAP` surface moisture files. There was not need to downvote my question since you're not even answering it...

Comment: SMAP data is in a standard HDF5 format and I am having no issues loading it into ENVI or IDL and viewing the soil moisture data, which is one of the rasters in the hdf file.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Weird, I'm using the last version of `ENVI` (5.3). Could you please give me the link to the file you successfully loaded into ENVI?

Comment: [@JeffreyEvans is right, ENVI support hdf5. you can find details in given link](http://nsidc.org/support/98396298-How-do-I-import-and-geolocate-SMAP-Level-1C-and-Level-2-data-in-ENVI-)

Comment: https://nsidc.org/support/98396298-How-do-I-import-and-geolocate-SMAP-Level-1C-and-Level-2-data-in-ENVI- above link will describe how to open h5 in envi.

Comment: As links can go bad, please edit your answer to include the details necessary to answer this question in the future.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113230)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document explains exactly how to read `SMAP` moisture data: http://smap.jpl.nasa.gov/system/internal_resources/details/original/315_smap_hands_on_v1.pdf

Comment: You are basically right, but HDFview (at least mine on Windows) does not read HDF5 files. See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214265/opening-data-from-nsidc-in-qgis for solutions with Panoply and GDAL.