# Opening data from NSIDC in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, data, hdf, nasa

i download data from here https://nsidc.org/data/SPL2SMP/versions/3#,  but i can not open it in QGIS.

Do you know how to open this data in QGIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171865/how-to-open-smaps-surface-moisture-data-files)

Comment: Add as raster layer to QGIS, hdf5 format

Comment: @mdsumner have you tried one? I get a raster of X: 3 Y: 18570 cells. And HDF5view does not like the file.

Comment: Maybe related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200754/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-create-map-using-hdf-5-data-subset although the solution is for R.

Comment: Are two of the columns/ layers lon and lat? gdal warp in.h5 out.ti -t_srs "some projection" will probably work. What version of qgis is this? Also, just put details with the q, and details on what yiu tried exactly, it's all important.

Comment: @mdsumner gdalinfo reports the subdatasets are named `landcover class` and `landcover class fraction`. So no coordinate information. The data may follow the satellites  swath. BTW I am not the asker.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on working with nsidc modis data: http://wp.me/p2rn76-7C, it should be of use. It's written in R, but should be OK to follow.

Comment: What precisely happens when you try to open this in QGIS?

Comment: @PolyGeo you get a raster of 3 cells wide and 18570 cells high, without any usable geolocation information.

Comment: @AndreJ Perhaps the asker or you can [edit] that detail into the question so that it is not lost in the comment trail.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer MODIS seems to have relevant geolocation subdatasets, which are missing here.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have put that information into my answer already.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ, that's a fair point. It seems the SMAP L2 dataset are in an EASE-Grid 2.0 format (https://nsidc.org/data/ease/ease_grid2.html). NSIDC have instructions on preparing this for ArcGIS: http://nsidc.org/data/ease/gis.html#import-ease2, which should be adaptable for QGIS. The key point seems to be creating a header file.

Comment: @AndreJ  I was still reading the question and comments, and had not realized that you had made the assumption that the asker's workflow and results were identical to yours.

Comment: @MikeRSpencer this works for the L3 datasets, but with a different cellsize. See my extended answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo can you try a sample file with Arcgis?

Comment: @AndreJ Perhaps, where is it and how big is it? Do you just want me to input it to [this tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/extract-subdataset.htm)?  I've never worked with HDF.

Comment: @AndreJ, nice work!

Comment: @PolyGeo just take the first one from ftp://n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org/SAN/SMAP/SPL2SMP.003/2016.08.01/ only 1320kB. I would like to know if any subdataset can be imported into Arcgis.

Comment: @AndreJ There were two subdatasets that came in 0 and 1 to create 2 bands, 3 columns and 18567 rows with values from 0 to 99.  I rarely work with raster data and cannot afford to spend more time on this one but I hope that helps.

Comment: @PolyGeo seems to be the same mess as with GDAL. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raster can be loaded into QGIS with the `HDF5` driver, but it gets displayed as X: 3 Y: 18570 cells. Gdalinfo reports just 2 subdatasets, but no longitudes or latitudes.

The information on the website notes that latitudes and longitudes should be stored in separate subdatasets, along with several other datasets.

Using H5dump from [HDF Tools](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html) and [HDF Compass](https://support.hdfgroup.org/projects/compass/), the missing tables appear, so this seems to be an unusual HDF5 storage that GDAL imports only partially. The current Windows binary of HDFview does not like HDF5 files at all.

Looking closer, you see that most datasets are one-dimensional arrays, with the EASE Grid row and cell number, latitude and longitude stored in separate datasets. Empty cells are simply discarded, saving much table space.

GDAL does not seem to like those 1-D tables. The landcover_class table that GDAL can read consists of 3 columns with the three dominant landcover classes per EASE grid cell. But without lon/lat information you can not use it.

I finally managed to get the SMAP L2 data tables with [Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) exported as longitude, latitude and landcover_class CSV files, merged them into one CSV table with Libre Office, and imported that as delimited text points into QGIS:

[image]

As you can see, this is a dataset from just one half-orbit.

The [SMAP L3](http://nsidc.org/data/SPL3SMP) dataset works far better. You can extract a subdataset with

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -17334194 7356860 17334194 -7356860 -a_srs epsg:3410 -a_nodata -9999 HDF5:"smap_l3.h5"://Soil_Moisture_Retrieval_Data/soil_moisture sm.tif
```

to get a picture of all orbits of the day:

[image]

Unfortunately, this does not work for the landcover_class dataset, which comes as 3-dimensional (the three dominant land cover classes per EASE grid cell). GDAL tries to extract 406 bands of a 3x964 array, instead of 3 bands of a 964x406 array as intended by the data provider.